# Can log4net create log files in a yyyy\\MM\\ddMMyyyy_file.log structure?

Tags: c#, log4net, app-config

I am trying to make log4net create it's log files in a folder structure, but so far I'm not successful.

What I'd like to accomplish is that log4net creates log files like this:

```
..\log\2017\10\30-10-2017_eva360Recorder.log
..\log\2017\10\31-10-2017_eva360Recorder.log
..\log\2017\11\01-11-2017_eva360Recorder.log
..\log\2017\11\02-11-2017_eva360Recorder.log
```

In my app.config I now have the following:

```
  <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="log\\%date{yyyy}\\%date{MM}\\%date{dd-MM-yyyy}_eva360Recorder.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxDateRollBackups value="60" />
      <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy" />
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %M - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

This, however, results in the following:

```
d:\Eva360\Recorder\log\2017\10\31-10-2017_eva360Recorder.log
d:\Eva360\Recorder\log\2017\10\31-10-2017_eva360Recorder31-10-2017.log
```

As you can see, this is not what I wanted. It did not create a month folder (..\2017\11..) and also did not change the name of the log file, but added a date within the file name.

Is what I want even possible? 
If so, how should I do that? 
And also importantly, where is this to be found in the documentation of log4net?

Comment: I'm sure you've got your uses but I'm curious, why do you want double data? (year and month)

Comment: The structure is, ..well, for structure. The complete file name is useful for when I have to copy/email one or more files for investigation.

Comment: Try rollingStyle composite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599908/create-a-folder-for-each-day-and-a-new-file-when-max-size-is-reached

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this conjecture, rather than a definitive answer, but this could probably be achieved through the use of a custom log4net appender. See [IAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Appender_IAppender.htm) in the log4net SDK.

Google is chock full of articles about creating custom log4net appenders, so no need to repeat anything here.